# Were there mutual celebrations of Ederlazi and St.George's day in Ottoman Greece?

Tags: greece, festival, muslims, orthodoxism, ottoman

**Ederlazi** ([Hıdırellez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C4%B1d%C4%B1rellez)) celebrations of Muslims was a culturally intermixed celebration of the **[St.George's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_George%27s_Day)** of Christians. They were both celebrated on the 6th of May in the Balkans. Especially in **North Greece**, if not in larger **Macedonia**, were the two religious groups living together (in the same villages / towns) celebrating both festivals mutually in the **late Ottoman period**? How was it celebrated mutually, if that's the case? Otherwise, were celebrations totally separate?

Comment: What is missing from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C4%B1d%C4%B1rellez) page? "it is important to note that Hıdırellez doesn't have any links to Islam, rather it is a cultural practice." and "People, Muslims and Christians, regardless of their religious affiliation, celebrate the living Alkhidr prophet that is St. George or Mar Georgeos"